# Find the volume of solid of revolution $z^2 \geq x^2+y^2$ which is located inside the region formed by the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the volume of solid of revolution $z^2 \geq x^2+y^2$ which is located inside the region formed by the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

From the given data I can see that $$-\sqrt{(z^2-y^2)}\leq x \leq \sqrt{(z^2-y^2)}$$

Also I see that for $x=0$ in the (yz plane) I have $$-\sqrt{(1-z^2)}\leq y\leq\sqrt{(1-z^2)}$$

From the surface I understand that $$-1 \leq z\leq 1$$

So my answer should be $$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{(1-z^2)}}^{\sqrt{(1-z^2)}}\int_{-\sqrt{(z^2-y^2)}}^{\sqrt{(z^2-y^2)}}1dxdydz$$

The above integral does not give me the correct answer, can somebody plz check where is my mistake?

Note: I imagine there are several ways to solve this but I am trying to understand how to do it with integrals!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably helps to visualize this region: It looks sort of like a double ice cream cone. There are two cones whose points meet at the origin, and then they each meet the sphere and you get two spherical caps. The reason you get 2 is the problem does not specify $z \geq 0$. But for now, let's just focus on a single cone, where $z \geq 0$. Let $V$ denote this volume (so the final answer is $2V$).

If you want to do this in rectangular coordinates, the best way is to figure out when the figure stops being a cone and the spherical cap begins. In other words, find the intersection of the two constraints: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. We get $2z^2 = 1$, or $z = \sqrt{1/2}$.

Now below this critical value of $z$, the cone determines the boundary of the region. So you get that $-z \leq y \leq z$, and $-\sqrt{z^2 - y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}$.

Above this critical value, the sphere determines the boundary, so you get $-\sqrt{1 - z^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1 - z^2}$, and $-\sqrt{1 - z^2 - y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{1 - z^2 - y^2}$, so the final answer is:

$$V = \int_0^{\sqrt{1/2}}\int_{-z}^{z}\int_{-\sqrt{z^2 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 - y^2}}dxdydz + \int_{\sqrt{1/2}}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1 - z^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - z^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1 - z^2 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - z^2 - y^2}}dxdydz$$

However, this is much easier in cylindrical coordinates: $r, \theta, z$. The equations become $r^2 = z^2$ and $r^2 + z^2 = 1$. Here there is no bound on $\theta$, as the whole picture is symmetric. The maximum radius occurs on the intersection of the cone and the sphere, when $z = \sqrt{1/2}$ as above, so $r^2 = 1/2$. So for the radius we get $0 \leq r \leq\sqrt{1/2}$. Finally for the $z$ coordinate: The upper bound is the value of $z$ on the sphere ($z = \sqrt{1 - r^2}$) and the lower bound is the value of $z$ on the cone ($z = r$). And so:

$$V = \int_0^{\sqrt{1/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r}^{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}rdrd\theta dz$$

Finally, this is easiest in spherical coordinates. The region described is just saying that the angle from the vertical $z$ axis is at most the angle formed by the cone, which is $\pi/4$. So the volume is:

$$V = \int_0^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\rho^2 \sin(\theta)d\rho d\theta d \phi$$

Comment: Can u explain  why $z\geq 0$?

Comment: The problem allows for $z \geq 0$ and $z \leq 0$. However, it's conceptually easier to focus on just one of these regions, and then multiply your final answer by $2$.

Comment: So in your answer with double integral I should multiply by 2 the V acquired by double integrals?

Comment: I mean Have you already multiplied by 2 in your answer or not?

Comment: It was not included. I edited it to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you bound $-\sqrt{1-z^2}\leq y\le\sqrt{1-z^2}$ you are taking all the points $(x,y,z)$ inside and in the surface of the cylinder $y^2+z^2=1$. Instead of that you must take only the points which are inside the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and inside of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

---

You can find the volume using spherical coordinates, by symmetry we have 
\begin{align}
\text{Volume }&=2\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{\rho=0}^1\rho^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos 0-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\,\mathrm d\theta\\
\color{blue}{\text{Volume }}&\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{3}\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)
\pi}
\end{align}